# Blank space right side to a card in a container - Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I'm trying to make a card which is responsive to most screen sizes but I'm running into an issue. There is some blank space on the right side of the card on a mobile screen size which is not what I want. Is there a way to make this centred on small screens? I'm using Bootstrap 4. Example of my code is like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="mt-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 mr-lg-5 mt-4">
                <div class="card text-center" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                        <img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top embed-responsive-item" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x600" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 mr-lg-5 mt-4">
                <div class="card text-center" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                        <img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top embed-responsive-item" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x600" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the picture of the blank space on right side
[image: Screen size is 575]

Comment: change `col-sm-6` to `col-sm-12`

Comment: The result is still the same @ShashankGb

Comment: You need card to be one below other in mobile screen and it should be centered right?

Comment: Yeah. One card below another and centered

Comment: It says `col-xs-12` works for `<576px` and `col-sm-12` works `between 576px and 768px` see document here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#grid-options

Comment: It still gives me the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `.mx-auto` to your `div.card`s

```
<div class="card text-center mx-auto" style="width: 18rem;">
```